# ruby on rails ,checkout SVN

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I go to window-->preference-->click SVN-->then select-->javaHl then I get this error:

```
Error loading javaHL library
Failed to load javaHL 
 these are the errors that where encountered
 no libsvnjavahl -1 in java.libray.path
 no svnjavahl -1 in java.libray.path
 no svnjavahl  in java.libray.path
java.libray.path=home/kingston/radrails/jre/lib/i386/server:/home/kingston/radrails/jre/lib/i386:/home/kingston/radrails/jre/lib/i386:/:user/java packages/lib/i386/lib/user/lib
```

Also, please tell me how to install SVN in linux-ubuntu-radrails and aptana radrails.

Comment: 1/ The second question is not a programming question. 2/ What exactly is your first question?

Answer (score 1):

Your Subversion installation isn't complete. If you're running a Java-based Subversion client, as suggested by your post, you need the JavaHL library too. This provides the glue between the Java API and the core SVN DLLs. This page can tell you more:

http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

As to your second question, that's not a programming issue, and Google will help I'm sure.